# Erlang - Starting a child from the supervisor module

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm trying to create a supervisor which handles adding dynamic gen_servers. for a reason something is failing and I'm not really sure what.

```
-module(supervisor_mod).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0, add_child/1]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
    Pid=supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE} , ?MODULE, []),
    {ok,Pid}.

init(_Args) ->
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 10, 60},
          [{example_proc, {example_proc, start_link, []},
            permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [example_proc]}]}}.

add_child(Name)->                                                                        
    supervisor:start_child(supervisor_mod,
                           {example_proc, {example_proc, start_link, []},
                            permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [example_proc]}).
```

and

```
-module(example_proc).
-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2]).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

init(Args) ->
    io:format("~p (~p) started...~n", [Args, self()]),
    {ok, []}.

handle_call(alloc, From, State) ->
    {reply, From, State}.

handle_cast({free, _Ch}, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.
```

in erl shell:

```
Eshell V5.8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> supervisor_mod:start_link().
{ok,{ok,<0.33.0>}}
2> supervisor_mod:add_child(aa).
{error,{'EXIT',{badarg,[{erlang,apply,
                                [example_proc,start_link,
                                 {example_proc,{example_proc,start_link,[]},
                                               permanent,brutal_kill,worker,
                                               [example_proc]}]},
                        {supervisor,do_start_child_i,3},
                        {supervisor,handle_call,3},
                        {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}}}
```

Any help/explanation/solution is appreciated,
/s.

Comment: Passing [] as the second argument to start_child solves it. T he point is I am planning to extend the module to accept an argument passed to the gen servers. how is this done ?

Comment: [] are the arguments. Whatever you pass in there, will be ++'ed to the arguments you specified in the generic worker template returned from init/1

Comment: A sidenote: in supervisor_mod:start_link/0 you are returning {ok, Pid} which in the end means {ok, {ok, Pid}}, because your Pid variable is the return of supervisor:start_link/3 (which is alredy in the format {ok, Pid}), so you might want to just return the result of supervisor:start_link/3 directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [OTP Doc:](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2) in case of simple one for one strategy, in start_child function you can pass arguments as a list for the child start_link function of the child.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `simple_one_for_one` all the children will use the same ChildSpec, the one given in the `init/1` callback and this initialisation can only return **one** ChildSpec. Also in this case the second argument to `supervisor:start_child/2` must be a list and **NOT** a ChildSpec. This list is a list of extra arguments which is appended to the argument list given in the default ChildSpec and it is this combined argument list which is used when calling the child's start function. This is how the `simple_one_for_one` children all can use the same ChildSpec and still can get in specific arguments to them.

In your case as there was an empty list in the ChildSpec and you called `start_child/2` with an empty list the total number of arguments to the start function was `0`. Which matched how your `start_link/0` function is defined.

An alternative is in your case to use `one_for_one` and start each child with its own ChildSpec. More complex but also more versatile.

Unfortunately this dual use of `supervisor:start_child/2` has made it inconsistent in its arguments.